# How do I include google play service on AOSP besides using Gapp

Tags: google-play-services, android-source

I installed own build android image on Intel NUC mini-computer which doesn't include google play services by default. Android image build from [link][1].

can anyone tell me how to include google play service? i dont think [Gapp][1] work for me, i need another solution for this.

thanks

Comment: Your "links" are apparently dead.

Comment: Android image build from link. please refer to http://http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Google Apps And Services on Lollipop AOSP ROM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110170) and [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27809)